# Use shell if defined in LDAP, otherwise default

Tags: linux, ldap, shell, sssd

How should `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` file be configured to use the shell defined in LDAP and the default one if the variable is not defined in LDAP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is exact purpose of the `default_shell` directive in the [sssd.conf](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sssd.conf) configuration file

> ```
> default_shell /bin/bash
>
>       The default shell to use if the provider does not return one
>                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
>       during lookup. This option supersedes any other shell option
> ```

Comment: Thank you! and the shell defined in LDAP is taken automatically? or must be set the variable in krb5.conf?

Comment: If your LDAP returns a shell that is the one that will be used, when It doesn’t the user will have the `default_shell`